# Using JNA program to call self written C code in MAC

Tags: java, macos, jna

It is my g++ version
[g++ version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnZjH.png)

It is myself defined c code

```
void hello() {
  printf("Hello, World!\n");
}
```

I put **libtest_dll.dylib** below the src
This is my Java code.I use maven to load jna and jna-platform

```
public interface IDemo extends Library {
  IDemo I_DEMO = (IDemo) Native.load("lib_test_dll", IDemo.class);
  void hello();
}
public class demo {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
System.setProperty("jna.library.path",
     "/Users/tangrunze/golang-project/go-original/tangrunze/src/");
    IDemo.I_DEMO.hello();
  }
}
```

When i run Java code,it's will response this.Running on win is no problem

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'test_dll':
dlopen(/Users/username/golang-project/go-original/username/src/libtest_dll.dylib, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/username/golang-project/go-original/username/src/libtest_dll.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /Users/username/golang-project/go-original/username/src/libtest_dll.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
dlopen(/Users/username/golang-project/go-original/username/src/libtest_dll.dylib, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/username/golang-project/go-original/username/src/libtest_dll.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /Users/username/golang-project/go-original/username/src/libtest_dll.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
dlopen(/Users/username/Library/Frameworks/test_dll.framework/test_dll, 9): image not found
dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/test_dll.framework/test_dll, 9): image not found
dlopen(/System/Library/Frameworks/test_dll.framework/test_dll, 9): image not found
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:307)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:467)
    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.<init>(Library.java:192)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.load(Native.java:622)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.load(Native.java:596)
    at com.trz.jna.IDemo.<clinit>(IDemo.java:7)
    at com.trz.jna.demo.main(demo.java:7)
    Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen(/Users/username/golang-project/go-original/username/src/libtest_dll.dylib, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/username/golang-project/go-original/username/src/libtest_dll.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /Users/username/golang-project/go-original/username/src/libtest_dll.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
        at com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native Method)
        at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:197)
        ... 6 more
    Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen(/Users/username/golang-project/go-original/username/src/libtest_dll.dylib, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/username/golang-project/go-original/username/src/libtest_dll.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /Users/username/golang-project/go-original/username/src/libtest_dll.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
        at com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native Method)
        at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:210)
        ... 6 more
    Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen(/Users/username/Library/Frameworks/test_dll.framework/test_dll, 9): image not found
        at com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native Method)
        at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:254)
        ... 6 more
    Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/test_dll.framework/test_dll, 9): image not found
        at com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native Method)
        at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:254)
        ... 6 more
    Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen(/System/Library/Frameworks/test_dll.framework/test_dll, 9): image not found
        at com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native Method)
        at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:254)
        ... 6 more
```

Comment: I put the dll file below the src package

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is your dylib on the classpath or on a path you've declared with `jna.library.path`?  Have you tried it by including "lib" in the JNA loading or by excluding "lib" in the filename?

Comment: I has already add jna.library.path, use `System.setProperty("jna.library.path",
     "/Users/username/project/src");`

Comment: Please run with the command line `-Djna.debug_load=true` and add the log results of the library search to your question.  (See the [FAQ](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/c517796826673ee8bb65d72d10de2f3ac4f57593/www/FrequentlyAskedQuestions.md#calling-nativeload-causes-an-unsatisfiedlinkerror))

Comment: I just added the question

Comment: `src` is not supposed to be an output directory - and a `dll` is not a `dylib`.

Comment: My computer is mac,not support dll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this line:

Did find:
/Users/username/golang-project/go-original/username/src/libtest_dll.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture

You have compiled your dylib for a different architecture than what your JVM is compiled for.

“mac” as you say it, is not an architecture. Over the years it has seen many archs

- x86-32
- x86-64
- arm

Not to mention the older power architecture … (not that you will see many binaries or libraries for that, but still …)

If your JVM is compiled for one of these then it will only load dylibs compiled for that specific architecure.

A 32 bit x86 process will only load 32bit x86 libs, likewise an x86-64 process will load libraries of that architecture only.

Bottom line: Make sure that you compiled your lib for the same architecture as the JVM’s.

Comment: Thanks,I just changed Java from x64 to arm64. :)